# Service "doctrine_mongodb" not found / Symfony / Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I am trying to flush in symfony with MongoDB and when i do :

```
$dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
```

I have this error when i do the command :

> Service "doctrine_mongodb" not found: even though it exists in the app's container, the container inside "AppBundle\Controller\api\MessageUserController" is a smaller service locator that only knows about the "doctrine", "form.factory", "http_kernel", "request_stack", "router", "security.authorization_checker", "security.csrf.token_manager", "security.token_storage", "session" and "twig" services. Unless you need extra laziness, try using dependency injection instead. Otherwise, you need to declare it using "MessageUserController::getSubscribedServices()".

There is my config.yml :

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where 
the app is deployed
parameters:
locale: en
image_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/web/uploads/images'

framework:
#esi: ~
#translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
secret: '%secret%'
router:
    resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
    strict_requirements: ~
form: ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation: { enable_annotations: true }
#serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
default_locale: '%locale%'
trusted_hosts: ~
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: 
'%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
fragments: ~
http_method_override: true
assets: ~
php_errors:
    log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
form_themes:
  - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: 
'%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
transport: '%mailer_transport%'
host: '%mailer_host%'
username: '%mailer_user%'
password: '%mailer_password%'
spool: { type: memory }

sensio_framework_extra:
request: { converters: true }

fos_rest:
view:
    formats: { json: true, xml: false, rss: false }
    view_response_listener: true
    mime_types:
        json: ['application/json', 'application/json;version=1.0', 
'application/json;version=2.0']
serializer:
    serialize_null: true
body_converter:
    enabled: true
    validate: true
    validation_errors_argument: violations
#format_listener:
 #   rules:
 #       - { path: 'api/', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 
'json' }
exception:
    enabled: true
    codes:
        { AppBundle\Exception\ResourceValidationException: 400 }
    exception_controller: 'fos_rest.exception.controller:showAction'
versioning:
    enabled: true
    resolvers:
        media_type: # Accept header
          enabled: true
          regex: '/(v|version)=(?P<version>[0-9\.]+)/'

lexik_jwt_authentication:
private_key_path: '%jwt_private_key_path%'
public_key_path: '%jwt_public_key_path%'
pass_phrase: '%jwt_key_pass_phrase%'

doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    default:
        server: "%mongodb_server%"
        options: {}
default_database: Boojon_db
document_managers:
    default:
        auto_mapping: true
```

My controller :

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\api;

use AppBundle\Document\MessageUser;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Security;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;

/**
* @Security("is_anonymous() or is_authenticated()")
* @Route("api")
*/
class MessageUserController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 *
 * @Rest\Post(
 *     path = "/message/user/add",
 *     name = "api_message_add"
 * )
 * @Rest\View(StatusCode=201)
 */
public function UserAddMessageAction(Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $content = ($request->get('content'));
    $user = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' 
=> ($request->get('id_user'))));
    $token = $request->get('token');
    $friend = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:User')- 
>findOneBy(array('id' => ($request->get('id_friend'))));


    if (!isset($content) ) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Message non renseigné"
        ]);
    }

    if (!isset($token)) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Token non renseigné"
        ]);
    }

    if ($user->getToken() != $token) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Bad token",
        ]);
    }

    if (!isset($friend) or !isset($user)) {
        return new JsonResponse([
            'success' => "false",
            'message' => "Message sans propriétaire ou destinataire"
        ]);
    }

    $message = new MessageUser();
    $message->setRead('0');
    $message->setIdReceiver($friend->getId());
    $message->setIdTransmitter($user->getId());
    $message->setSendAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    $message->setContent($content);

    $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
    $dm->persist($message);
    $dm->flush();

    return new JsonResponse([
        'success' => "true",
        'message' => "Message ajouté"
    ]);
}
}
```

Thx for all that will try to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractController` is a simpler base controller, it has no full container support, your options are:

Inject doctrine_mongodb/manager service directly trough constructor/method argument.

or

Extend from `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller` instead of `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`

Comment: when i use controller i have this error that i don't understand : Attempted to load class "ObjectID" from namespace "MongoDB\BSON".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: Do you have php mongodb extension enabled?